# Make an exposed node reference filter to show only nodes created by current user

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I am having a little problem I cannot figure out how to solve.

I have a 3 content types:

- campaign
- post
- publication

Post contains a node reference to campaign. Publication contains a node reference to post. I am making a view that lists all publication and I would like to give user an option to filter them by campaign.

However when I am making an exposed filter that allows a user to select a campaign to filter and it works just fine, but I am not able to figure out how to limit exposed filter options to campaign nodes created only by current user?

I know how to do this through code, but I'd like to figure out if this is possible to do via UI.

[image]

Comment: **before** the filter is applied, do you want to list nodes by everyone? or the current user only?

Comment: I want that filter options would be only campaigns created by current user

Comment: understood, but before the filter happens/gets applied, is it only current user? or everyone?

Comment: The publication nodes that are shown by the view are only of current user. I added a contextual filter to deal with that, but the filter options (campaign nodes) are still by everyone.

Comment: hmm that's odd, what did you use for contextual filter?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/NQJQCVnYHCB - my contextual filter

Comment: What is in that drop down? node titles? or ???

Comment: Yes, node titles of campaign nodes.

Comment: How did you add it? adding title as filter does not look like that.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/nMZ8FOf6

Comment: which module are you using to create the node references? [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) ?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/references

Answer (score 1):

Either it's a bug by the [references](http://drupal.org/project/references) module or works as designed.

You can accomplish your goal using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) modules.

In Views, add relationship of Referenced Entity.

Click the <kbd>+Add</kbd> button and add an entity reference view.

Add relationship of Referenced Entity (this is probably already done as it clones your current view) and make field title have a relationship. Remove all other unnecessary fields, if you have them, and just leave the title (make sure you select *for This entity reference (override)*, so it doesn't affect your page view).

In settings, checkmark ☑ content title.

[image]

Now go back to your page view and add your entity reference field as a filter.

Comment: DId you actually try it? I am not even seeing an exposed filter in your view.

Comment: Yes, I did, the screen shot is from the Entity Reference view (as you can see in the top right under **Displays**). The expose filter is in the Page view.